# win10 + softwares in a disk image for all hardwares

Tags: windows, installation, microsoft-office, disk-image, adobe-creative-suite

3 relatives of mine need a fresh install of windows,
I want to make a disk image containing **win10** + notfree softwares such as **office19** and **adobe2020** suites assuming :

- they are already activated on the machine I get them
- the machine owner paid for more than one software host
- all destinations would be laptop hardwares, as the image host, some with iGPU and some with dGPU, all with intel branded processors
- different gpu brands
- I would install dedicated gpu drivers only after I installed the disk image

1) Do you know if this should work flawlessly ? (so that I could start saving for a 128/256GB usb stick)

2) If not, do you know about tools similar to Ansible (used for linux machines) that proceed to the different installs automatically ?

Comment: It absolutely is possible to create Windows installation that already contains the desired software.  How you do that is an extremely broad topic, with multiple approaches, and requires far more details then an answer will allow.  So if your stick at a specific step, that’s something easily answered, but documenting the entire process in an answer won’t be possible. Ansible Tower most commonly used for deployment of Windows images is paid software.

Comment: For just 3 machines it's not worth it. You can spend weeks and make multiple test installs to prepare this image.

Comment: I agree with both posts above, but particularly with the time aspect and we do not try to do this when getting 2 or 3 new computers. It is faster and easier to set them up. (1) Consider a Repair Install as that fixes most (not all) problems and may work for you . (2) Unless you have another reason, Office 365 personal subscription is a better deal than the one time only Office 2019.  Your relatives will be better off with Office 365.